# Why is .pgpass file not supplying a password for the pg_dump, vacuumdb, or reindexdb commands?

Tags: bash, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pg-dump

I'm trying to execute several different PostgreSQL commands inside of different `bash` scripts. I thought I had the `.pgpass` file properly configured, but when I try to run `pg_dump`, `vacuumdb`, or `reindexdb`, I get errors about how a password isn't being supplied. For my `bash` script to execute properly, I need these commands to return an exit code of 0.

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.5.4 on macOS 10.12.6 (16G1408).

In an admin user account [neither `root` nor `postgres`], I have a `.pgpass` file in `~`. The `.pgpass` file contains:

```
localhost:5432:*:postgres:DaVinci
```

The user is indeed `postgres` and the password is indeed `DaVinci`.

Permissions on the `.pgpass` file are `600`.

In the `pg_hba.conf` file, I have:

```
# pg_hba.conf file has been edited by DaVinci Project Server. Hence, it is recommended to not edit this file manually.
# TYPE    DATABASE    USER    ADDRESS    METHOD
local    all    all    md5
host    all    all    127.0.0.1/32    md5
host    all    all    ::1/128    md5
```

So, for example, from a user account [neither `root` nor `postgres`], I run:

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/pgAdmin3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/pg_dump --host localhost --username postgres testworkflow13 --blobs --file /Users/username/Desktop/testdestination1/testworkflow13_$(date "+%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M").backup --format=custom --verbose --no-password
```

And I get the following error:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "testworkflow13" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I get the same result if I run this with `sudo` as well.

Curiously, `pg_dump` *does* execute, and *does* export out a `.backup` file to the `testdestination1` directory, but since it throws an error, if it's in a `bash` script, the script is halted.

Where am I going wrong? How can I make sure that the `.pgpass` file is being properly read so that the `--no-password` flag in the command works?

Comment: What happens if you specify `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`?

Comment: @jeremysprofile That worked! Buy why? On a different system, `localhost` used to work. What would I need to be doing to get `localhost` to work?

Comment: This invocation with `localhost` and `.pgpass` works fine for me on linux. Not only that, but having `127.0.0.1` in pg_dump and `localhost` in .pgpass or vice versa doesn't work.

Comment: Note that `localhost` might resolve to `::1` and not `127.0.0.1` which is why a software can never hardcode that they're the same thing.

Comment: @DanielVérité I'll try commenting out the IPv6 line in `pg_hba.conf` and see if `localhost` will work in the command again.

Comment: @DanielVérité I don't really understand. I I comment out the IPv6 line in the `pg_hba.conf` file, and try to run the command with user `localhost`, I get this error: `pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "testworkflow14" failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "postgres", database "testworkflow14", SSL off`

I don't need to do it in IPv6. Ideally, I just want `localhost` to work instead of having to use `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @DanielVérité I hopped into `/etc/hosts` and saw that both `127.0.0.1` and `::1` were set to `localhost`. There's a comment there that warns not to edit the file--but I'm not sure why I would need IPv6 for my local network. Could you advise whether I could just comment out the IPv6 line?

Comment: @user260467: to me that's a red herring. The Look up in .pgpass occurs before resolving the host argument. The problem in your question is that your invocation of pg_dump should work as is it (as it does for me).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out that changing all three lines in the `pg_hba.conf` file to the `trust` method of authentication solved this.

`local    all    all        trust
host    all    all    127.0.0.1/32    trust
host    all    all    ::1/128    trust`

Since the method is `trust`, the `.pgpass` file may be entirely irrelevant--I'm not sure, but at least I got it working.

Comment: never do that out of NON-production environmnet because it basically remove the postgres firewall

Comment: It's fine behind a trusted network-wide firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Please start with a read to [official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/libpq-pgpass.html).
Also, even this topic is more than 2 years also, i strongly suggest to update to at least to version 10, anyhow nothing relevant has been changed around .pgpass

.pgpass need to be chmod 600, fine, the user that uses that must can read, so that must be the owner of that file.

Please remove the *--no-password* that just confuse and is not needed.

Using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost clarify where you are going, "usually" are the same.

> ... from a user account [neither root nor postgres] ...

The user you are using for must have read access to .pgpass, as said, so you have to clarify that and provide that file to that user, maybe using the PGPASSFILE env variable could be useful for you.

Another way is the use of [.pg_service.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/libpq-pgservice.html) file with or without the .pgpass, for what you have written it looks like that may be more appropriate

Also you could set the PGPASSWORD in the env of the user.

Think about security, some choices look the simpliest but can expose accesses .. and as DBA I'm frankly tired about peoples that store password in visible places, printed in logs or on github or set "trust" in pg_hba and finally comes to me to say "postgreSQL is insecure".. hahaha!

Final note, you do not have a pg_hba error, in case you will have a "pg_hba" error message.